# Designing my password class(es). How to split it up?

Tags: design, php

I've inherited a custom made authentication system that needs some refactoring.  I'm not quite sure what the best way to split it up the password section and could use some help.

**The password class(es) need the following functionality:**

- **Check to see if a password conforms to restrictions.** It needs to be able to provide feedback on why it is incorrect.
- **Generate three kinds of hashes.**  We have several file-systems with incompatible hashes, so unfortunately I have to maintain three hashes.
- **Give a different hash for a certain user type.** If a user is web-only we do not keep a password for them as they cannot use the system.  Their passwords are always `*`.
- **Be able to verify a password for a given user.** Fortunately I only have to authenticate against one of the three hashes I have to maintain.
- **Be able to generate a random password, unencrypted.**
- **Submit new password to the database.**

---

I'm thinking about using four classes, `Validator`, `Hasher`, `Generator`, and `Changer`.

- Validator

  - `isCurrentPassword(int userid, string password): bool`
  - `getViolations(string password): array`
- Generator

  - `generate(int length):string` Creates a password.
- Hasher

  - `hash_*(string password): string` where `*` is the hash type.  I'll have four hashing functions.
- Changer

  - `change(int userid, string password):void; throws database exceptions`

---

**What would you recommend and why?**

Answer (score 2):

Who else is supposed to use this authentication system? If it is only your application, use the simplest code possible that can be understood, maintained and tested.  However, I don't see that you should use 2 separate classes as in method 1, because Validator is not a class it is strictly a method of some class. The same goes for Generator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check to see if a password conforms to restrictions

   I think this belongs in its own class. In your method 1, you've got it as part of the Validator class. But it doesn't have the same dependencies as `isCurrentPassword` or share any implementation details. As a result, I'd put in a seperate PasswordAudit class.
2. Generate three kinds of hashes

   You should have some sort of interface which provides uniform access to the different filesystems you are using. I'd suggest the `hash()` function should live there. Its an implementation detail of the filesystem, and belongs in your handling for that filesystem
3. Give a different hash for a certain user type

   If they can't use the system, why do they have accounts? Or perhaps they can login into the web system, but don't have access to the filesystem backends? But in that case, they'd still have a password wouldn't they?

   I'd suggest implementing this by a NullFileSystem backend. The backend would support the interface of a filesystem, but not actually work. Overriding the hash is easily done.
4. Be able to verify a password for a given user.

   I'd be inclined to use the user object for this purpose. It would have an authenticate method which determines whether the given password matches the user object.

Of course, I've only got a glimpse of what you are doing, so my suggestions may or may not make any sense.

Comment: Regarding #3: They don't have access to the file system but that doesn't mean they don't have accounts.   The authentication for these users happens upstream from my website. I'm in a sub-organization.

Comment: @LeviMorrison, then I wonder why you need to do any authentication. Can't you use the upstream authentication?

Comment: I can't use upstream authentication for the file-system access because the hashes are invalid, and I don't have access to the upstream hash.

Comment: Also, I don't do anything with the file system.  The web interface simply provides a way to do things with passwords, such as password resetting.

Comment: @LeviMorrison, so your system resets the passwords on backend filesystems for the users from the website?

Comment: As far as this specific snippet is concerned, yes.

Comment: @LeviMorrison, so what does the interface to the file systems look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 interfaces:

- IPasswordValidator : validates password / handles UI messaging about validation.
- IAuthenticationScheme : handles the authentication / hashing / updating of passwords

IPasswordValidator probably only needs one concrete implementation but it is simple enough to put it behind an interface to document the contract at least. Testability is a bonus. IPasswordValidator covers your getViolations method.

IAuthenticationScheme is where the fun happens -- this is where you wire up your alternate hashing schemes and whatever data dependencies you have. In your original scheme this combines hasher and changer and your isCurrentPassword classes and methods.

Generation isn't really a concern covered in either, it would probably be best left to a utility library. If generation is implementation dependent -- such as if a certain provider had any particular requirements -- you could move generation into IAuthenticationScheme.